# Getting error while using jQuery multislider, Uncaught TypeError: u is not a function at multislider.min.js:9

Tags: jquery-plugins

I keep getting error while using jQuery multislider for sliding multiple items in the slider, following is my code.

```
<head>       
    #exampleSlider {
       position: relative;
       border: 1px solid black;
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
      #exampleSlider {
      border-color: transparent;
   }
 }


     #exampleSlider .MS-content {
     margin: 15px 5%;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     border: 1px solid red;
 }


   @media (max-width: 767px) {
       #exampleSlider .MS-content {
       margin: 0;
   }
   }

     #exampleSlider .MS-content .item {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: top;
     border: 1px solid green;
     border-right: none;
     width: 20%;
   }

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
      #exampleSlider .MS-content .item {
      width: 25%;
    }
  }

@media (max-width: 992px) {
      #exampleSlider .MS-content .item {
      width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
       #exampleSlider .MS-content .item {
       width: 50%;
    }
  }

   #exampleSlider .MS-content .item p {
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 1;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 10px 0;
    }

   #exampleSlider .MS-controls button {
     position: absolute;
     border: none;
     background: transparent;
     font-size: 30px;
     outline: 0;
     top: 35px;
   }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
      #exampleSlider .MS-controls button {
      display: none;
  }
}

  #exampleSlider .MS-controls button:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
}


  #exampleSlider .MS-controls .MS-left {
     left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
      #exampleSlider .MS-controls .MS-left {
      left: -2px;
  }
}

  #exampleSlider .MS-controls .MS-right {
     right: 10px;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
       #exampleSlider .MS-controls .MS-right {
       right: -2px;
  }
}


       </head>
       <div id="exampleSlider1" class="exampleSlider">
             <div class="MS-content">
                 <div class="item">
                   <p>Item<br>9</p>
               </div><div class="item">
                   <p>Item<br>10</p>
               </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>1</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>2</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>3</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>4</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>5</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>6</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>7</p>
            </div><div class="item">
                <p>Item<br>8</p>
            </div></div>
        <div class="MS-controls">
            <button class="MS-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button class="MS-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/new-js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/new-js/multislider.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#exampleSlider').multislider({
            interval:5000,
            slideAll:true
        });
        });
</script>
```

I have downloaded the code from https://www.multislider.info/ where it work according to my desire but in my page it show me the above error in the title of the question and also I'm  not getting the slider rather my items are displayed is plain html not in slider, what may be wrong as I'm using the same code is an the site above where it's work fine, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `id="exampleSlider1"`  And `$('#exampleSlider').multislider({` .. its not the same id .. change `id="exampleSlider1"` to `id="exampleSlider"`

Comment: still not working